# Yii - Dynamic add a Logging Routes

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to manage a custom logging service on DB.

I've partially followed the following guide:

[Log Activity in Database](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/521/log-activity-in-database/)

Now I have my LogDB class:

```
    class LogDB extends CDbLogRoute
{

    public $logTableName = "genericLog";

    protected function processLogs($logs)
    {
        $command = Yii::app()->myAppDb->createCommand();
        $logTime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

        foreach($logs as $log)
        {
            $command->insert($this->logTableName,array(
                'level'=>$log[1],
                'category'=>$log[2],
                'logtime'=>$logTime,
                'userName'=>Yii::app()->user->name , 
                'requestURL'=>Yii::app()->request->url, 
                'message'=>$log[0]
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunally I cant add new rows to main.php so I have to add dyanmically in the place I have to use it.

I have tried, in the method I have to use the DB LOG, to use this:

```
$cc = Yii::app()->getComponent('log');
            $cc->setRoutes(array(
                                    'class'=>'LogDB ',
                                    'connectionID'=>'db',
                                    'enabled'=>true,
                                    'levels'=>'info',
                                ));
```

Then in my method, I have this simple log call:

```
Yii::log(serialize($debugParameters), CLogger::LEVEL_INFO);
```

Of course, no log in DB are written and I have no visible error on screen.
Is this the right way?

Im not finding an example on google on how use setRoutes.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I have finally resolved the problem.

setRoutes command doens't want an array like in main.php but an object that extends *Route.

```
$cc = Yii::app()->getComponent('log');
$dbLogRoute = new LogDB();
$dbLogRoute->enabled = true;
$dbLogRoute->levels = 'info';
$customRoutes = array($dbLogRoute);
$cc->setRoutes($customRoutes);
```

IMPORTANT: setRoutes overwrite previous routes so remember to call getRoutes (that return a CMAP) and rebuild an array (CMap is readonly so you cant add directly).